# Find the Coefficient of $x^8$ by Multinomial Theorem Expansion for $(1+x^2-x^3)^9$

Tags: multinomial-coefficients, multinomial-theorem

**Problem:** Find the coefficient of the term $x^8$ for the expansion of $(1+x^2-x^3)^9$
**Attempt:**
By the multinomial theorem:
$$(1+x^2-x^3)^9=\sum_{b_1+b_2+b_3=9}{9\choose b_1,b_2,b_3}(1)^{b_1}(x^2)^{b_2}(-x^3)^{b_3}$$
This means a general term for the expansion of $(1+x^2-x^3)^9$ will be in the form of
${9\choose b_1,b_2,b_3}(1)^{b_1}(x^2)^{b_2}(-x^3)^{b_3}$
We achieve $x^8$ by letting $b_1=5,b_2=4,b_3=0$, it follows that:
$${9\choose 5,4,0}(1)^{5}(x^2)^{4}(-x^3)^{0}=126x^8$$
**My Question:**
The actual answer is $378$, what am I missing?

Comment: $b_3 = 2$, $b_2 = 1$ is missing

Comment: Yes, missed that. Thanks!